# UIViewController modal segue not all views are visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

So i have a really weird one.  In a storyboard scenario, I manually perform a segue to do a modal present of another view controller.  The new controller has no code associated with it yet, just the boilerplate UIViewController .h and .m.

When the view controller is presented, only about 1/2 of the controls are visible.  After about 20 seconds or so, the rest show up.  After about 10 seconds or so, if I tap anywhere on the view, the rest show up.

I've created a few outlets and looked at things like the frame of one of the views that isn't visible, and it's coordinates are valid.

????[image: when immediately preseneteed]

[image: after...]

Comment: Seems really strange! I would try to remake the storyboard viewController that is having the issues, since a regular storyboard vc with no code in it should have no problem displaying itself, surely! Make a new one and try segueing to that one instead? Sometimes that works

Comment: idiocy...  should have known but just haven't seen this behavior for a long time.  was pushing the controller on a background thread, from a block in an NSURLSession...  sigh...

Comment: Hey, it happens!  :)